# R: selecting a different row at every column efficiently

Tags: r, performance, subset

I have a matrix:

```
x = rbind(1:5, 6:10)
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

I want to select a different row for each column based on an index.  For instance I might want to get a new vector that looks like

```
[1]  1  2  8  4 10
```

by selecting rows `c(1,1,2,1,2)` at the appropriate columns.  I can do it thus:

```
diag(x[c(1,1,2,1,2),])
[1]  1  2  8  4 10
```

but that is memory inefficient because it create this matrix:

```
x[c(1,1,2,1,2),]
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    6    7    8    9   10
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

Given a real dataset and multiple iterations I am concerned about a severe performance issue. How can I extract the same values based on my index *efficiently*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing

```
 x[cbind(c(1,1,2,1,2), 1:ncol(x))]
 #[1]  1  2  8  4 10
```

Comment: interesting. never knew that it is possible before.